# Showing json data in dynamic jqgrid

Tags: dynamic, jqgrid

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/GridTest/getTestData",
            datatype: "json",
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            success: function (result) {
                $("#dataGrid").jqGrid({
                    datatype: 'jsonstring',
                    data: result,
                    gridview: true,
                    colModel: result,
                    height: "auto",
                    loadComplete: function (data) {
                        alert('loaded');
                    },
                    loadError: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert('error');
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function (x, e) {
                alert(x.readyState + " " + x.status + " " + e.msg);
            }
        });
    });

        string result = "['Id', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Last 4 SSN', 'Department', 'Age', 'Salary', 'Address', 'Marital Status']";
```

Hello,

I have problem with showing json data in dynamic jqgrid.I am using this json string at serverside and set column names and data to this string at ajax function.Grid is loading but does not show anything at page. I tried many alternatives but could not show json data in jqgrid. What is wrong with my way here?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, but nothing is clear. First of all you use `datatype: "json"` of `$.ajax` insstead of `dataType: "json"`; you use `data: result` and `colModel: result`, but the `data` and `colModel` should have different format; you use `datatype: 'jsonstring'`, but provides the input data using `data` parameter instead of `datastr` (`data` parameter will be used in case of `datatype: 'local'`). It's unclear which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.8.2/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.8.2/src/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.8.2/src/grid.base.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.8.2/src/grid.common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.8.2/src/grid.formedit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.8.2/src/grid.inlinedit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.8.2/src/grid.celledit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.8.2/src/grid.subgrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.8.2/src/grid.treegrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.8.2/src/grid.grouping.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.8.2/src/grid.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.8.2/src/jquery.fmatter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.8.2/src/jquery.searchFilter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.8.2/src/grid.jqueryui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.8.2/src/jqDnR.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.8.2/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.8.2/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>-->

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            //url: "../DynamicColumnBinding.txt",
            url: "/GridTest/getTestData",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (result) {
                var colD = result.couponStripList,
                    colM = result.colModelList;

                alert(typeof(result));
                $("#dataGrid").jqGrid({
                    datatype: 'local',
                    data: colD.rootVar,
                    gridview: true,
                    colModel: colM,
                    height: "auto",
                    loadComplete: function (data) {
                        alert('loaded');
                    },
                    loadError: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert('error');
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function (x, e) {
                alert(x.readyState + " " + x.status + " " + e.msg);
            }
        });
    });


        string dataFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/DynamicColumnBinding.txt"));
        jss.Serialize(text);
        return Json(dataFile, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Before this code, i tried your solution at stackoverflow.com/questions/5111653/… as it is, but didnt work at me. I got 404 Undefined error while reading txt file.I got the datas you pasted and saved to txt file. If i could run it, i would change it by returning the json string from dynamically at serverside

Comment: 1) you should **append** additional information to the text of your question (click on "edit" button under of the question). You should post the answer on your own question only if you solved the problem yourself and you what to share the results with other readers. 2) you should not use retro versions like jqGrid 3.8.2, jQuery 1.5.1 and jQuery UI 1.8.10. Instead of that you should use for example [free jqGrid 4.12.1](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), jQuery 1.11.3, jQuery UI 1.11.4 **see [here](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#the_first_grid)**

Comment: You can use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or Developer Tools of IE/Chrome to see which data really returns "/GridTest/getTestData" and to include the data from HTTP trace in the text of your question. I wrote you already that the usage of `colModel: result` and `data: result` (the same value) have no sense. `colModel`  described the columns of the grid and `data` contains the corresponding data.